# How can I remove the effect when switch button changes state in android

Tags: android, button, switch-statement

How can I remove the grey circle (as in the below image) appearing when a switch button changes the state in Android 5.1.1?
[Effect when Android's switch changes state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEbKD.png)

Comment: It is known as ripple effect and can't be removed as it is integrated in android itself

Comment: you use `Switch` or `SwitchCompat`?

Comment: Switch, unfortunately. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. I really appriciate your information

Answer (score 20):

You need to set background of Switch to disable ripple effect. In my case i set background null to achieve this.

```
 <Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvStateDefault"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:thumb="@drawable/customswitchselector"
    android:track="@drawable/custom_track"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: You can set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` as well.